# how to move background image left to right?

Tags: java

I am making a game using Java where I want the background image to move from right to left. and I want to keep repeating so it will look like the player is moving.

I wrote below code to do this but there is a problem with it. Image will move from right to left twice but 3rd image wont show up. any idea?

```
public void update() {
    x -= dx;
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g) {

    // 1st image
    g.drawImage(image, (int) x, (int) y, GamePanel.WINDOW_WIDTH, GamePanel.WINDOW_HEIGHT, null);

    // keep scrolling the image
    // there will be two same bg image on screen
    if (x < 0) {
        g.drawImage(image, (int) x + GamePanel.WINDOW_WIDTH, (int) y, GamePanel.WINDOW_WIDTH, GamePanel.WINDOW_HEIGHT, null);
    }
    if (x > 0) {
        g.drawImage(image, (int) x - GamePanel.WINDOW_WIDTH, (int) y, GamePanel.WINDOW_WIDTH, GamePanel.WINDOW_HEIGHT, null);
    }
}// End of draw method
```

it look like value of x is keep on dec for ever so I added this code but still there is 1 part where image is missing:

```
if(x+GamePanel.WINDOW_WIDTH < 0){
            x = GamePanel.WINDOW_WIDTH;
        }
```

Comment: It looks like you haven't changed the value of x anywhere, so x will just keep decreasing and never loop back around properly.

Comment: can the x ==0? that scenario is not covered in draw method and could be the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple. Simply put the two images next to each other, and don't forget to reset the x at some point.

Since each image is as wide as the window, first you'll see only the 1st image. Then it is getting scrolled to the left, and the other image slides in from the right. After scrolling so much that only the 2nd image is visible, you can switch back to the start. (I assume it is a simple platform scroller, and the two images are identical.)

```
|11111|
|11112|
|11122|
|11222|
|12222|
|11111| as above
```

In code:

```
public void update() {
    x -= dx;
    if (x<-GamePanel.WINDOW_WIDTH) {
        x+=GamePanel.WINDOW_WIDTH; 
        // or reset to zero
    }
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g) {

    // 1st image
    g.drawImage(image, (int) x, (int) y, GamePanel.WINDOW_WIDTH, GamePanel.WINDOW_HEIGHT, null);

    // 2nd image right to 1st image
    g.drawImage(image, (int) x + GamePanel.WINDOW_WIDTH, (int) y, GamePanel.WINDOW_WIDTH, GamePanel.WINDOW_HEIGHT, null);

}// End of draw method
```